# nio or io for server handling 1000 concurrent file uploads/downloads?

Tags: java, io, scalability, nio

So people are telling NIO is faster and scales better than IO.Will it be the same for a server handling 1000 concurrent GET/PUTs ?

Simple thread per model utilises multiples core to the max.Where does NIO stand at this respect?

Is there any way to combine both of these?If so,any links on details would be better.

Comment: nio all the way, it's quite a pity most head to head tests have terrible nio code. on the very very plus side, w/ nio (and non-windows, windows emulates it) you have the benefit of **transferTo**, IO can't touch that.

Comment: @bestsss transferTo() is a myth. There is no kernel usage, not even any JNI code. Have a look at the implementation. It's just the same code you would write yourself.

Comment: @EJP, now you're wrong, look at the sources - i have done that i can claim i know NIO impl. incl. native code pretty well. Linux and Solaris do support it properly, hint http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile . Windows does not (SendFile doesn't take a fd but pathname).

Comment: @bestsss I did look at the sources. There is no implementation for `transferTo()` in src/{solaris,windows}/**/*.java, JDK 1.6, latest I have. Linux sources not distributed. src/share/classes contains the implementation I described above.

Comment: @EJP, well ok, another hint: native/solaris/sun/nio/ch /FileChannelImpl.c `Java_sun_nio_ch_FileChannelImpl_transferTo0(JNIEnv *env, jobject this,
                                            jint srcFD,
                                            jlong position, jlong count,
                                            jint dstFD)`
note, linux and solaris share the same native code (some #IFDEF here and there...] relevant part of the impl `offset = (off_t)position; n = sendfile(dstFD, srcFD, &offset, (size_t)count);`

Answer (score 1):

Tens years ago NIO scaled much better than IO, largely because the number of threads you could efficiently use was relative small. esp on Linux systems. e.g. a few hundred threads. Today the tipping point is much higher e.g. around 10,000. If you need 100,000 connections, using NIO is a good idea. However if you only have a few thousand you are likely to find other issues such as your disk or network performance is far more critical.

I almost always use NIO with one thread per blocking connection.  In fact the default behaviour until NIO2 in Java 7 is blocking Sockets and Files. BTW NIO2 uses a thread pool to support its "asynchronous" IO. ;)

Comment: having too many threads sucks for latency as you effectively rely on the OS to do the priority of the reads/writes. For throughput/bulk transfer that's not so crucial. For real time alike stuff (gaming, market data, VoIP, etc) getting a lag spike is truly undesirable.

Comment: @bestsss How exactly is having the operating system schedule threads according to priority in probably multiple CPUs worse than having your application loop around a selected key set with no priority in a single thread and therefore probably in a single CPU?

Comment: @EJP, what makes you think you should use *probably* a single CPU? For example: on Windows having more than 64 keys per selector is not efficient (waitForMultipleObjects takes max 64 sockets). Priority is the same for all threads in linux as well, i.e. it's ignored. Having one thread is the most naive approach if you are to serve thousands of connections.

Comment: @bestsss How is a single thread looping around a selected-key set *not* going to use a single CPU?

Comment: I have found that using selectors instead of blocking threads to be more efficient for a large number of connections. However, the number of "large" has been getting higher and higher over the years with improvements in software/hardware. The point at which Selector + NIO is preferable may be so high that simplicity is more important than performance (IMHO, it usually is) I usually prefer NIO + blocking threads, which is an option which isn't used as much as it should.

Comment: @EJP, you use more than a single selector and more than a single thread obviously, just not a selector<->thread (blocking reads poll/recv anyways, just like selector). Like I've told I do claim to known how NIO is impl. and where its shortingcomings are.

Comment: @bestsss Using multiple selectors/threads can make more sense when your application has real work to do for each connection. If the work it does is basically IO bound, using more threads is unlikely to make much difference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, but then again, if you are IO bound there is no fairness sending the (small/medium) messages and the latency for some clients spikes up depending how the OS schedules the threads. my first remark. If you do bulk stuff it's all ok, but if you have small/mid and maybe larger messages and the TCP window scales up, the larger ones gets some extra benefits saturating the network for brief moments. Side note: you can saturate the network w/ a single TCP socket (unless you run winxp)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to links posted by @Kumar, I found this one helpful (was doing this research a few weeks ago): http://paultyma.blogspot.com/2008/03/writing-java-multithreaded-servers.html.

See the associated slides as well for more detailed stats. He makes the argument for the java.io approach. Of course, as with everything, it depends on the use case.